# ServiceStack Authentication with thirdy part token

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, servicestack

I’ve to implement authentication for our app. The app will be integrated in a thirdy part system that will send a token to our app. 
We were thinking of making a call to the ServiceStack authentication service and if the response is positive continue with the code, otherwise show an error popup. 
Is this the right implementation? Or do we need to use the authenticate attribute to trigger the authentication process? We confuse when to use the attribute and when not.. any explanation is welcome. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would call the Authenticate Service to Authenticate the HTTP Client using one of the registered Auth Providers, the [Authenticate Attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#the-authenticate-attribute) would only be used to protect services to ensure they can only be called by authenticated users.

Comment: One more question @mythz: in a web project in a SSO scenario, where the client is the browser and therefore I have no explicit way to use the authentication service, does the process take place because of the authenticate attribute?

Comment: If you're referring to [OAuth Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#oauth-providers), the authentication still initiates with the /auth/{oauth} endpoint, before redirecting to the 3rd Party Login which upon successful authentication redirects back to the /auth/{oauth} endpoint with an Access Token which is used by the OAuth Provider to establish an Authenticated Session with ServiceStack.

Comment: I was referring to a case where WindowsAuth is planned, but I guess IIS, for example, handles the process under the hood, so in case it makes a call to /auth/{provider} endpoint @mythz